# Maximum Stack Error When trying to Deploy with Gulp SFTP plugin

Tags: javascript, sftp, gulp

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy using gulp and the gulp-sftp plugin:

> gulp deploy [gulp] Using gulpfile
>   ~/Coding/*****/gulpfile.js [gulp] Starting 'deploy'... [gulp]
>   Authenticating with private key.
>
> /Users/ethan/Coding/*****/node_modules/gulp-sftp/node_modules/gulp-util/lib/PluginError.js:25
>   Error.call(this);
>           ^ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I've installed both gulp and gulp-sftp locally, and my gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var sftp = require('gulp-sftp');

gulp.task('deploy', function() {
    return gulp.src('out/*')
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: 'code-cuts.com',
            user: 'codecuts',
            remotePath: '/stageing.code-cuts.com'
        }));
});
```

Does anyone what might be the source of this error. There's not much of a clue from the error message as far as I can tell.

Comment: ran into the same thing... no clue what's going on. Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. My problem was using the incorrect key name "password" instead of "pass" when specifying the password. In your case, it looks like you may need to do the same? (add the "pass" with your password). Now I'm dealing with unexpected behavior from the "remotePath" key, but that is unrelated to your posting about exceeding the maximum call stack.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are receiving this error because you haven't provided the `pass` property to the sftp() function.